# Using Enchantment nbt tag in json recipe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm making a mod in 1.12.2 and I want to create a recipe when a sword + an enchanted book makes the same type of sword but with the enchants of the enchanted books. (diamond sword + an enchanted book of sharpness level 4 or 5 makes an diamond sword enchanted sharpness 6)

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
  "group": "enchanted_swords",
  "pattern": [
    "P",
    "B"
  ],
  "key": {
    "P": [
      {
        "type": "minecraft:item_nbt",
        "item": "minecraft:enchanted_book",
        "nbt": {
          "StoredEnchantments":
          "id": 16
          "level": 4
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "minecraft:item_nbt",
        "item": "minecraft:enchanted_book",
        "nbt": {
          "StoredEnchantments":
          "id": 16
          "level": 5
        }
      }
    ],
    "B": {
      "item": "minecraft:water_bucket"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "type": "minecraft:item_nbt",
    "item": "minecraft:water_bucket",
    "nbt": {
      "StoredEnchantments":
      "id": 16
      "level": 6
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

I tried to use this [link](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2949913-using-nbt-in-recipe-input) but it only showed for potions so I had to try using the enchanted book wiki but it showed the patern in words not in code so I need help please

Comment: dont use a pastebin. instead have the code in the question

Comment: does anyone knows how?